# I want to take tagcleaned html source with turkish characters therefore i need to combine this code witth a charset

Tags: python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: iso-8859-9 -*-

import urllib2
import urllib
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
from formatter import NullFormatter
from urllib2 import URLError
import cookielib
import urllib,time
import urlparse
import datetime
import new
from htmllib import HTMLParser
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
import urllib2
import sys,popen2,os
import urlparse

def tagclean(url,Data=None):

    html =  urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    doc = fromstring(html)
    tags = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6',
       'div', 'span', 
       'img', 'area', 'map']
    args = {'meta':False, 'safe_attrs_only':False, 'page_structure':False, 
       'scripts':True, 'style':True, 'links':True, 'remove_tags':tags}
    cleaner = Cleaner(**args)

    path = '/html/body'
    body = doc.xpath(path)[0]
    return cleaner.clean_html(body).text_content().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

i will add this code the this main code:

```
DEFAULT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'

def parse_content_type(response):
    try:
        ctype = response.info()['Content-Type']
    except KeyError:
        raise URLError('No Content-Type defined.')
    try:
        ctype, encoding = ctype.split(';')
        # encoding is now "charset=enc"
            _, encoding = encoding.split('=')
    except ValueError:
        # no or wrong encoding definition, use default
        encoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING
        try:
            ctype = ctype.split(';')[0]
        except IndexError:
            raise URLError('Could not parse Content-Type: "%s"' % ctype)

    return ctype, encoding

//This function should return "text/html" as Content-Type.

ctype, encoding = parse_content_type(response)

if not ctype == 'text/html':
    raise URLError('Wrong Content-Type: "%s"' % ctype)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this [still](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992644/i-want-to-add-charset-to-this-charset-solve-the-code-haves-charset-the-website-c) doesn't make any sense. Please ask a clear and concise question.

Comment: yes it is complex i didn't edit well as well i want to edit main code tagclean when u saved turkish charactered pages it is deleting turkish characters don't print turkish characters...Printing webpage source without turkish characters..."ş,ç" for example

Comment: Please edit the question and add what is it that you're having problems with and what's the expected outcome.

Comment: just edit the question if you understood me

Comment: I didn't. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`good_stuff.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` will delete your Turkish characters and anything else that's not ASCII. Don't do that. As you seem to be using `ISO-8859-9`, try using that to encode your Unicode characters.

What operating system are you using?

Comment: it worked john i want to take main website urls seperated seperated and take sources tagcleaned can you add this code to url-html source code crawler.

Comment: @germandenis: I don't understand anything after "it worked john".

Comment: i want to take for example www.google.com with google's urls and I want to take the urls' source codes seperately i wanted to say i want a website url+html source code crawler.THis tagclean code will combine with url spider.